# Web3 Module Not Found

Tags: reactjs, web3js

I am adding Web3 module to my React app.

But I am getting the following list of errors when I run "npm start"

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 3:16-43

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'F:\02_Workspace\04_Mathew\Frontend\node_modules\cipher-base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 9:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'F:\02_Workspace\04_Mathew\Frontend\node_modules\eth-lib\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/account.js 71:31-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in 'F:\02_Workspace\04_Mathew\Frontend\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\dist.browser'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
    - install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 30:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'F:\02_Workspace\04_Mathew\Frontend\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 32:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'F:\02_Workspace\04_Mathew\Frontend\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib/helpers.js 11:12-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'F:\02_Workspace\04_Mathew\Frontend\node_modules\web3-providers-ws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }
```

I created my React app by running "npx create-react-app"
This is package.json file

```
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "reactstrap": "^9.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "web3": "^1.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I think this is a module version problem, but don't know exactly.
Before, I can use web3 only by installing web3 module, but now I can't.